Pass data to PostgreSQL database from back end error
int roleId = 0;
int maxRoleId = 0;
int maxTempRoleId = 0;
int result = 0;

try
{
    using (DBConnector oCloudConnection = new DBConnector(connectionValues[0], Convert.ToInt32(connectionValues[1])))
    {
        StringBuilder varname1 = new StringBuilder();
        varname1.Append("SELECT MAX(CAST(ROLE_ID AS INT)) AS MAX_ROLE_ID \n");
        varname1.Append("FROM SROLE \n");
        varname1.AppendLine("WHERE ROLE_ID ~ E'^\\d+$'");
        varname1.Append("AND COMPANY_ID=?COMPANY_ID \n");
        varname1.Append("AND PRODUCT_ID=?PRODUCT_ID;");

        oCloudConnection.CommandText = varname1.ToString();
        oCloudConnection.Parameters.Clear();
        oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "COMPANY_ID", Value = oROLEDTO.COMPANY_ID });
        oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "PRODUCT_ID", Value = oROLEDTO.PRODUCT_ID });
        using (IDataReader dr = oCloudConnection.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                maxRoleId = DataReaderHelper.GetValue<int>(dr, "MAX_ROLE_ID");
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
    }

in this code every time i run this maxRoleId become 0. I already check the postgresql query and it select max role id with out a problem but in maxRoleId = DataReaderHelper.GetValue<int>(dr, "MAX_ROLE_ID"); code line maxRoleId dosent get assign the value of MAX_ROLE_ID
I wanted to know how to fix this issue i also change the while loop to
if (dr.Read()) // Check if there are any rows returned
        {
            maxRoleId = DataReaderHelper.GetValue<int>(dr, "MAX_ROLE_ID");
        }
        else
        {
            maxRoleId = 0; // Set a default value (adjust as needed)
        }
        dr.Close();

to see if this works but it doesn't.
